# gunicorn + django + nginx -- recv() not ready (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)

Tags: python, django, nginx, gunicorn

I am getting this issue. I am trying to setup a server and cannot get it running. I am using django, gunicorn and nginx. here are the logs

nginx log

```
2018/02/09 22:22:32 [debug] 1421#1421: *9 http write filter: l:1 f:0 s:765
2018/02/09 22:22:32 [debug] 1421#1421: *9 http write filter limit 0
2018/02/09 22:22:32 [debug] 1421#1421: *9 writev: 765 of 765
2018/02/09 22:22:32 [debug] 1421#1421: *9 http write filter 0000000000000000
2018/02/09 22:22:32 [debug] 1421#1421: *9 http copy filter: 0 "/?"
2018/02/09 22:22:32 [debug] 1421#1421: *9 http finalize request: 0, "/?" a:1, c:1
2018/02/09 22:22:32 [debug] 1421#1421: *9 set http keepalive handler
2018/02/09 22:22:32 [debug] 1421#1421: *9 http close request
2018/02/09 22:22:32 [debug] 1421#1421: *9 http log handler
2018/02/09 22:22:32 [debug] 1421#1421: *9 free: 000055D4A01ACBE0
2018/02/09 22:22:32 [debug] 1421#1421: *9 free: 000055D4A01C6FB0, unused: 0
2018/02/09 22:22:32 [debug] 1421#1421: *9 free: 000055D4A01B9F80, unused: 214
2018/02/09 22:22:32 [debug] 1421#1421: *9 free: 000055D4A01C9460
2018/02/09 22:22:32 [debug] 1421#1421: *9 hc free: 0000000000000000 0
2018/02/09 22:22:32 [debug] 1421#1421: *9 hc busy: 0000000000000000 0
2018/02/09 22:22:32 [debug] 1421#1421: *9 reusable connection: 1
2018/02/09 22:22:32 [debug] 1421#1421: *9 event timer add: 3: 70000:1518215022208
2018/02/09 22:22:32 [debug] 1421#1421: *9 post event 000055D4A01D8BD0
2018/02/09 22:22:32 [debug] 1421#1421: *9 delete posted event 000055D4A01D8BD0
2018/02/09 22:22:32 [debug] 1421#1421: *9 http keepalive handler
2018/02/09 22:22:32 [debug] 1421#1421: *9 malloc: 000055D4A01C9460:1024
2018/02/09 22:22:32 [debug] 1421#1421: *9 recv: fd:3 -1 of 1024
2018/02/09 22:22:32 [debug] 1421#1421: *9 recv() not ready (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
2018/02/09 22:22:32 [debug] 1421#1421: *9 free: 000055D4A01C9460
```

gunicorn log:

```
[2018-02-09 22:21:35 +0000] [2514] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 2514)
[2018-02-09 22:21:35 +0000] [2510] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 2510)
[2018-02-09 22:21:35 +0000] [2523] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 2523)
[2018-02-09 22:21:35 +0000] [2501] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
[2018-02-09 22:21:36 +0000] [2556] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.7.1
[2018-02-09 22:21:36 +0000] [2556] [INFO] Listening at: unix:/var/www/myapp/application/live.sock (2556)
[2018-02-09 22:21:36 +0000] [2556] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[2018-02-09 22:21:36 +0000] [2563] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 2563
[2018-02-09 22:22:31 +0000] [2556] [CRITICAL] WORKER TIMEOUT (pid:2563)
[2018-02-09 22:22:32 +0000] [2598] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 2598
```

what can it be? I am stuck for hours now.

here is my gunicorn service:

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn daemon
After=network.target

[Service]
User=www-data
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory={{ app_dir }}
ExecStart={{ virtualenv_dir }}/bin/gunicorn --workers 1 --bind unix:{{ app_dir }}/live.sock {{ wsgi_module }}:application --error-logfile /var/log/gunicorn.log

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: Are those `{{ ... }}` literal or just placeholders for posting here?

Comment: @heemayl just placeholders from ansible playbook

Answer (score 1):

If you kept your wsgi file settings default, try this:

```
{{ project_dir }}.wsgi:application
```

And in your code:

```
WorkingDirectory={{ project_dir }}
ExecStart={{ virtualenv_dir }}/bin/gunicorn --workers 1 --bind unix:{{ app_dir }}/live.sock {{ project_dir }}.wsgi:application --error-logfile /var/log/gunicorn.log
```

You are running gunicorn from your **app** directory, but instead run it from your **project** directory.